# pandas - efficiently computing combinatoric arithmetic

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that look like such:

```
            BestBid    BestOffer
Strike                          
800     1253.900024  1256.599976
900     1154.199951  1156.800049
1000    1054.400024  1056.900024
1050    1004.500000  1007.000000
1100     954.599976   957.000000
            ...          ...
2350       0.050000     0.400000
2400       0.000000     0.200000
2450       0.000000     0.600000
2500       0.000000     0.600000
3000       0.000000     0.600000
```

And I want to compute a grid of all pairwise combinations of the index, and compute some arithmetic operation on the pairs. My code below is how I do it iteratively (and slowly):

```
output = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=df.index)
for pair in itertools.combinations(df.index, 2):
    if pair[0] >= pair[1]:
        continue
    low= pair[0]
    high= pair[1]
    spread = df.loc[high, 'BestBid'] - df.loc[low, 'BestOffer']
    output.loc[low, high] = spread
```

`output` ends up looking like:

```
     800    900    1000   1050   1100   1125   1150   1175   1200   1220   1225   1240  ...     2220     2225     2230     2240    2250     2275     2300     2350    2400    2450    2500    3000
800   NaN -102.4 -202.2 -252.1   -302 -326.9 -352.1 -376.8 -401.7 -421.7 -426.7 -441.6  ... -1256.05 -1255.85 -1256.25 -1256.45 -1256.5 -1256.45 -1256.55 -1256.55 -1256.6 -1256.6 -1256.6 -1256.6
900   NaN    NaN -102.4 -152.3 -202.2 -227.1 -252.3   -277 -301.9 -321.9 -326.9 -341.8  ... -1156.25 -1156.05 -1156.45 -1156.65 -1156.7 -1156.65 -1156.75 -1156.75 -1156.8 -1156.8 -1156.8 -1156.8
1000  NaN    NaN    NaN  -52.4 -102.3 -127.2 -152.4 -177.1   -202   -222   -227 -241.9  ... -1056.35 -1056.15 -1056.55 -1056.75 -1056.8 -1056.75 -1056.85 -1056.85 -1056.9 -1056.9 -1056.9 -1056.9
1050  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  -52.4  -77.3 -102.5 -127.2 -152.1 -172.1 -177.1   -192  ... -1006.45 -1006.25 -1006.65 -1006.85 -1006.9 -1006.85 -1006.95 -1006.95   -1007   -1007   -1007   -1007
1100  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  -27.3  -52.5  -77.2 -102.1 -122.1 -127.1   -142  ...  -956.45  -956.25  -956.65  -956.85  -956.9  -956.85  -956.95  -956.95    -957    -957    -957    -957
  ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...  ...      ...      ...      ...      ...     ...      ...      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2350  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN    -0.4    -0.4    -0.4    -0.4
2400  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN    -0.2    -0.2    -0.2
2450  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN    -0.6    -0.6
2500  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN    -0.6
3000  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Note that I make it slightly faster by not doing the operation if the first element of the pair is larger. This is essentially **n^2** computation time, is there any faster or vectorized way of doing this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy` allows you do do these calculations without a loop. Here we use an [`outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) subtraction to get all pairwise differences. Then mask the lower triangle.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(-1*np.subtract.outer(df['BestOffer'].to_numpy(),
                                        df['BestBid'].to_numpy()),
                   index=df.index.to_numpy(),
                   columns=df.index.to_numpy())

# `NaN` the lower triangle
df1 = df1.mask(np.tril(np.ones(df1.shape)).astype(bool))
```

---

```
      800         900         1000        1050        1100         2350         2400         2450         2500         3000
800    NaN -102.400025 -202.199952 -252.099976 -302.000000 -1256.549976 -1256.599976 -1256.599976 -1256.599976 -1256.599976
900    NaN         NaN -102.400025 -152.300049 -202.200073 -1156.750049 -1156.800049 -1156.800049 -1156.800049 -1156.800049
1000   NaN         NaN         NaN  -52.400024 -102.300048 -1056.850024 -1056.900024 -1056.900024 -1056.900024 -1056.900024
1050   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  -52.400024 -1006.950000 -1007.000000 -1007.000000 -1007.000000 -1007.000000
1100   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  -956.950000  -957.000000  -957.000000  -957.000000  -957.000000
2350   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN    -0.400000    -0.400000    -0.400000    -0.400000
2400   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN          NaN    -0.200000    -0.200000    -0.200000
2450   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN    -0.600000    -0.600000
2500   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN    -0.600000
3000   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC the calculation is `BestBid` minus `BestOffer` for each combination of values in `Strike`? If so this is a way I came up with that should be faster that basically constructs a pivot table from scratch:

```
pt = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=df.index)
for column in pt.columns:
    pt[column] = df.loc[column, "BestBid"] - df["BestOffer"]
```